# Downloading an image to gallery in Android - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an Android app that is getting multiple sorts of data from API calls (retrofit).
Now I'm getting some data from API like textual caption and an image or something. I want to give a button with an image that downloads the image to the gallery of the device.

I'm building this app using: Kotlin, Android Studio, and APIs.

Comment: you've listed your requirements ,what's preventing you from getting this done ? could you please add the code you've written so far to show what you're struggling with ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code for download image to gallery it's in koltin, I am sharing here please look into it.

Firstly you have to give permission in your AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Request Storage Permission

```
 private fun requestStoragePermissionAndDownload() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // Permission already granted, proceed with the download
                downloadImageToGallery()
            } else {
                // Request permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION
                )
            }
        } else {
            // For devices running SDK version less than 23 (Android 6.0), permission is granted in the manifest
            downloadImageToGallery()
        }
    }



  private fun downloadImageToGallery() {
        val bitmap = (imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

        // Get the Downloads directory
        val downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

        // Create a unique filename for the image
        val fileName = "image_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"

        // Create the file in the Downloads directory
        val file = File(downloadsDir, fileName)

        try {
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()

            // Add the image to the gallery
            addToGallery(file, this)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Image downloaded to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to download image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun addToGallery(file: File, context: Context) {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image saved from app")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.absolutePath)
        }

        context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    }
}
```

Here is code Which I have used to download image from gallery.

Comment: You are not downloading anything. You grab a bitmap from an image view and save it to storage. We wonder how you placed an image in the view.